# JetBrains dotPeek IDE unable to decompile code for Entity Framework select statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, jetbrains-ide, dotpeek

I have a dll having code of .NET Entity Framework. I am trying to generate source code from given dll. I am using JetBrains dotPeek to do so. But some portion of code is invalid and I am unable to guess what actually may be its correct source code.

This is the invalid code:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression;
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            // ISSUE: method reference
            System.Collections.Generic.List<PayrollRightsObligationDTOS> list = this.dbContext.PayrollRightsObligations.Select<PayrollRightsObligation, PayrollRightsObligationDTOS>(Expression.Lambda<Func<PayrollRightsObligation, PayrollRightsObligationDTOS>>((Expression) Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof (PayrollRightsObligationDTOS)), (MemberBinding) Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(__methodref (PayrollRightsObligationDTOS.set_PayrollROId)), )))); //unable to render the statement
```

Please let me know how can I get its equivalent correct code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try other decompilers like telerik justdecompile?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.